# SDWebImage how to use basic authentication

Tags: swift, sdwebimage

There are no information how to use SDWebImage with basic authentication in Swift. Can you tell me please, how I can make it?

For example, if I use Alamofire, I can did basic authorization:

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, URLString, encoding: .JSON)
    .authenticate(user: user, password: password)
....
```

I get URL address photo from Alamofire. Then I want to use SDWebImage for get image and set background for button uses this image.

I think I need to use `sd_setImageWithURL` for get image from server.

```
button.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: photo)!, forState: .Normal)
```

But I have basic auth and need to transfer username and password.

Comment: what do you mean by basic authentication. Explain more

Comment: and also add details as to what you have tried...

Comment: I added example from Alamofire

Comment: Hints: In *Alamofire*, look at `Request.swift` for `authenticate()`. You'll see it generates a `URLCredential` from `user` and `password`, and in 
*SDWebImage*, there are a few objects that have a `NSURLCredential` property. My guess would be too look at the code when you download an image, and check what kind of that object it called in the source, and check then where to put these credentials...

Comment: Thank you. I updated my issue

Comment: `SDWebImageDownloader.sharedDownloader.username = user; SDWebImageDownloader.sharedDownloader.password = password;`, but that's just a guess.

Comment: No, it is not working.

Comment: @Dim have you found any solution

Answer (score 0):

**SDWebImage 5** onward need to used following snipped code.

```
        func configureSDWebImageHeader(){
    let requestModifier = SDWebImageDownloaderRequestModifier { (request) -> URLRequest? in
        var mutableRequest = request
        // Used Your Header Keys
        mutableRequest.setValue("", forHTTPHeaderField: KeyConstant.USERID)
        mutableRequest.setValue("", forHTTPHeaderField: KeyConstant.AUTH_KEY)
        return mutableRequest
    };
    SDWebImageDownloader.shared.requestModifier = requestModifier
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let sdDownloader = SDWebImageDownloader.shared()
    sdDownloader.username = "username"
    sdDownloader.password = "password"
    let logoURL = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "communityLogo") as? String
    if let url = URL(string: logoURL!) {
        sdDownloader.downloadImage(with: url, options: .continueInBackground, progress: { (_, _, _) in

        }, completed: { (image, _, _, _) in
            self.communityLogoImage.image = image
            self.communityLogoImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        })

    }
```

Comment: Hi, no. But I used AlamofireImage for this.